# How can I add a UIToolbar to a UIViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uitoolbar

I have a UIViewController. I want to add a UIToolbar to the bottom, but IB is not letting me. How can I achieve this?

Note:
The UIViewController is part of a UINavigationController. I'm not sure if this affects the visibility of the toolbar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting from iOS 3.0 you can set toolbar items you want using following `UIViewController`'s method:

```
- (void)setToolbarItems:(NSArray *)toolbarItems animated:(BOOL)animated
```

of simply set or override `toolbarItems` property.

And toolbar will appear automatically if you put your view controller inside navigation controller.

Comment: Where does the toolbar appear? On the bottom of the view? Mine does not appear using the code:  `[self setToolbarItems: toolbarItems animated:NO];` //toolbarItems is an array that contains a UIBarButtonItem

Comment: I set the UIViewController's items, but it is part of a UINavigationController. Will this affect the visibility of the toolbar?

Comment: I had to make sure the toolbar was visible in my UINavigationController

Answer (score 0):

You can't add toolbar in IB, in IB all you can do is - set a dummy toolbar / navigation bar / tabBar etc. so that you can simulate them to arrange your view's subviews appropriately.

To set the toolbar for that viewController, you have to fill the UIViewController's:

```
setToolbarItems:animated:
```

or

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSArray *toolbarItems
```

so this toolbar and its items will be displayed when your viewController is presented.